# The code is for to plot naca airfoil. I received the out of bound error when printing yc

Tags: c++, indexoutofboundsexception

This code uses for loop to find values of yc by putting value of x in the equation.The error is "error: Mat::operator(): index out of bounds terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  Mat::operator(): index out of bounds".

```
#include<iostream>
#include<armadillo>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{

float a[3];
float c;
int gp = 100;

cout << "Please Enter NACA 4 digits" << endl;
cout << "Please Enter 1st digit" << endl;
cin >> a[0] ;
cout << "Please Enter 2nd digit" << endl;
cin >> a[1] ;
cout << "Please Enter last 2 digits" << endl;
cin >> a[2] ;
cout << "Please Enter Chord Length" << endl;
cin >> c;

float m=(a[0]*c)/100;
float p=(a[1]*c)/10;
float t=(a[2]*c)/100;

cout << m << endl;
cout << p << endl;
cout << t << endl;

vec x = linspace<vec>(0, c, gp);
vec yc = linspace<vec>(0, 1, gp);

for(int i=0;i<=100;i=i+1)
    {
        if (x(i)=0 && x(i) <= p){
        cout<< x(i)<<endl;
        yc(i)= (m/(p*p))*(2*p*(x(i))-(x(i)*x(i)));
    }
        else {
        yc(i)=(m/((1-p)*(1-p)))*((1-(2*p))+(2*p*x(i))-(x(i)*x(i)));
    }
    }
cout<<yc<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't a compiler error. As it looks, your i is going over the bounds of a vector, probably because that vector is smaller than 101 elements.

Comment: *isn't a compiler error* (@demonkoryu) ...but you are slowly approaching the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46358574/2932052 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linspace<vec>` is most likely a zero based array. With 100 elements, the last index is 99.

Therefore, replace

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i=i+1)
```

with

```
for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
```

I've replaced `i=i+1` as I find that notation unbearable.

Comment: difference between `++i` and `i=i+1` isnt only notation.

Comment: @tobi303 whats the difference? They both increment by 1, right?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah: potential atomicity for one.

Comment: `i=i+1` creates a temporary with the value of `i+1` and passes this to `operator=`

Comment: @tobi303: Although a modern compiler will take care of this, as I know you know ;-)

Comment: @Batsheba yes while writing I thought the same, but I dont like the idea of putting **all** knowledge of what the code is doing from the coder to the compiler

Comment: @tobi303: And neither do I. Which is why I'll always be an `++i` cat rather than an `i++` one.

Comment: @tobi303 Oh, ok, I thought you meant there was a _behavioral_ difference, which confused me for a second.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah yes this is indeed what I meant. For an int maybe it doesnt make a difference, given the compiler does its job of optimizing that unnecessary overhead away, but in general it can make a huge difference. Just think of iterators that have a `++i` but not `i++` or custom classes that can overload operators to do weirdest stuff

Comment: @ArnavBorborah consider the case where `i` is an object that is expensive to copy then you definitely should use `++i` that increments in place and not `i++` that makes a copy or `i=i+1` that comes with even more overhead

Comment: @Bathsheba The other problem is the value of yc is displaying same as x where it should be displaying calculated values of yc in for loop.

Comment: @tobi303 Ok, Thanks for clarifying!