# " 'yc' can not be used as a function" error in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am calculating NACA 4 digit airfoil coordinates using C++. In this code I used armadillo library's linspace function to divide x into linearly spaced points. When I use a for loop to calculate `yc`'s value for each `x`'s value I get error *"yc" can not be used as function*. Thanks for helping.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<armadillo>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
int main()
{

    float a[3];
    float c;
    int gp = 100;

    cout << "Please Enter NACA 4 digits" << endl;
    cout << "Please Enter 1st digit" << endl;
    cin >> a[0] ;
    cout << "Please Enter 2nd digit" << endl;
    cin >> a[1] ;
    cout << "Please Enter last 2 digits" << endl;
    cin >> a[2] ;
    cout << "Please Enter Chord Length" << endl;
    cin >> c;

    float m=(a[0]*c)/100;
    float p=(a[1]*c)/10;
    float t=(a[2]*c)/100;

    cout << m << endl;
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << t << endl;
    vec x = linspace<vec>(0, c, gp);
    float yc;
    for(int i=0;i<gp;++i)

        {
            if (x(i) = 0 && x(i) <= p){
            yc(i) = (m/(p*p))*((2*p*(x(i)))-(x(i)*x(i)));
        }
            if (x(i) > p && x(i) <= c) {
            yc(i) =(m/((1-p)*(1-p)))*((1-(2*p))+(2*p*x(i))-(x(i)*x(i)));
        }
        }
    cout<< yc <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What should `yc(i)` be??

Comment: Yc is equation of camber line.

Comment: Your code and response doesn't make sense. As asked, what do you want `yc(i)` be?

Comment: No matter what `yc` *means to you*, you declared it as a simple `float` variable and you actually are trying to call it as a function. It looks like you are trying to fill an array of floats with values calculated in the for loop. Every compiler will complain, if you don't talk to it in its language.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/46223437/2932052 ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

`yc` is a single float.

The compiler treats `symbol( )` as a function call.  That is what the error means.

Perhaps create an array of yc

```
float yc[gp];
```

and use

```
yc[i] = ....
```

As highlighted - `yc[gp]` may not work, so

```
float * yc = new float[gp];
```

And at the end of `main()`

```
delete []yc;
```

Comment: VLA's aren't standard c++.

Comment: Maybe using a `std::vector<float>` will be a better solution. If the asker is obviously new to C++ -- why leading them to use a "C-ish solution"?

Comment: `std::vector` also helps to avoid uninitialised data that could (formally) be caused by the `if` style shown by the OP, to me [that looks easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359745/2932052)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can use a `std::vector` for tasks of this kind.

The declaration of `vector<float> v(size);` fills the vector with `size` values of type `float` that are all set to `0.0` which is the standard value for `float`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// demonstrates how a vector is used as a better variadic array:
void vector_usage(int size){

    // initializing a vector with size 0 values
    std::vector<float> v(size);

    // fill in some (not very meaningful) values
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        if ((4 <= i) && (i < 8))
            v[i] = 15.0/i;
    }

    // inspect the result on console:
    for (auto e: v) {
        cout << e << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // hopefully having learned something ;)

}

int main() {
    vector_usage(12);
    return 0;
}
```

<sup>[See the live demo on ideone.com ...](https://ideone.com/D0AMn6)</sup>